# Migrating from PublishBuildArtifact to PublishPipelineArtifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, publish, .net-maui

I am trying to publish artifacts after building our .Net MAUI app on Azure Devops pipeline. It works when I do it like this:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifact@1
displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
inputs:
  PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/'
  ArtifactName: 'drop'
  publishLocation: 'Container'
```

After the pipeline runs, expected artifacts are created.

But I read that “PublishBuildArtfact” task is basically deprecated, and I should be using the “PublishPipelineArtifact” task. I tried to replace it as this:

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
inputs:
  targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/'
  ArtifactName: 'drop'
  artifactType: 'pipeline'
```

But no artifacts are created. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your YAML, it seems you just publish again not migrating it. There is an example in the official document to show how to migrate from PublishBuildArtifact to PublishPipelineArtifact:

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
 displayName: 'Publish'
 inputs:
  targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
      artifactName: 'prod'
  ${{ else }}:
      artifactName: 'dev'
  artifactType: 'pipeline'
```

For more information, you can check the [official document about migrating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml-task#migrate-from-build-artifacts).